# Display "burps" every 30 seconds

Tags: linux-mint, performance, cinnamon, freeze

I'm running Mint 18 on a Dell i7 and I have this annoying issue that I can't find where its coming from.

Every 30 seconds the display freezes for about 0.5 seconds. The issue is persistent and happens EXACTLY every 30 seconds (give or take 1 second).

This is particularly annoying when playing a game or watching a movie.

I couldn't isolate the process that may be causing this, but it wasn't there for the first week or so when I installed mint.

It may be worth to mention that I have another PC running Mint 17.1 that has the exact same issue (Also a Dell)

Anyone can think of a process that does something heavy and/or synchronous/blocking every 30 seconds?

I will provide any log file or additional info if anyone has any idea where should I look.

UPDATE:
This does not happen when I CTRL+ALT+F3, even when leaving all the processes alive in the graphical window.

Comment: Open `htop` and `iotop` or `glances` in a console to check whether there is a spike every thirty seconds.

Comment: thanks, but I already did that and there is no spike. It might be related to Cinnamon itself somehow or just some kind of a blocking process like a remote call that's not done asynchronously.

Comment: I've got the same issue. The process is `cinnamon` itself, and it uses 100% cpu on one core (I have 8, so it uses one) for 0.5 seconds every 30 seconds.

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using arch with cinnamon, so it isn't Linux Mint itself, it is primarily the `cinnamon` package that is glitching. I've tried removing all panel apps, and it didn't help at all.

Comment: Keep having this issue. Forgot how I fixed it, wound up here. Will report back if I fix it again...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: What is crossed out is only a temporary fix. The problem occurred again quickly after. Going to Settings > General > Miscellaneous Options and **disabling** "Enable support for indicators" fixed the issue for me. I looked in the log `~/.cinnamon/glass.log` and found that one of the indicators (owncloud client) kept restarting every 30 seconds, causing the issue.

<strike>Alright I solved the issue.</strike>

Rename `~/.cinnamon` to `~/.cinnamon-bak`.

In my case, at least, my version of `~/.cinnamon` has been around for a long time. Removing this folder (causing it to be recreated), fixed the issue, and no more lag spikes every 30 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with Mint 19.1. Noticed I had 2-sec freezes, which got steadily worse with time but upon testing, it affected my account only. So I deleted ~/.cinnamon from the command line. A process list simply had too much to bother isolating the offending program but at any rate, system works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, at least for my setup, external monitor over HDMI.

I fixed it by going to `Menu > Preferences > General`, enabling vblank, allowing compositing for full-screen windows, logging out of cinnamon and logging back in.